# unrecognized command-line option '-arch'; did you mean '-march='?

Tags: arm-none-eabi-gcc

I'm trying to build a STM32 project on MacBook M1 with CMake and arm-none-eabi-gcc.
These are my CMake codes:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(Embedded VERSION 0.1.0)


set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "arm-none-eabi-gcc") 

add_compile_options(-g -mcpu=cortex-m4 -O2 -Wall -Werror  -Wmissing-prototypes  -mlittle-endian   -fsingle-precision-constant -Wdouble-promotion)

add_executable(Embedded main.c)

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)
```

How can I make CMake generate -march instead if -arch?

Comment: why do you use CPAck

Comment: I'm using CMake tools on VScode, and its template has "include(CPack)", and I've tried to delete it but nothing changed.